# How to fix no transform from left and right drive wheels of the mobile robot to map in rviz2 in RPS2?

Tags: ros2, rviz, slam, urdf, ros-humble

I have mobile robot publish `/cmd_vel` topic from Roboteq Motor Controller. Also have 2D Lidar publish /scan topic with a frame id laser_link. My RealSense Depth camera D435if publish angular velocity under topic `/camera/camera/gyro/sample` and linear_acceleration under `/camera/camera/accel/sample`. Im using ROS2 humble under Ubuntu 22.04. Also set the config file for the robot_lokalization package and the launch file so I can use the SLAM slam_toolbox to generate the map and and autonomously navigate the robot. I can visualise the robot and generate the map in RVIZ2. But somehow when move the robot around I got the RVIZ2 error in the RobotModel and TF saying `No transform from [drivewhl_l_link] to [map]`and `No transform from [drivewhl_r_link] to [map]`. Here my ekf.yaml file

```
### ekf config file ###
ekf_filter_node:
    ros__parameters:
# The frequency, in Hz, at which the filter will output a position estimate. Note that the filter will not begin
# computation until it receives at least one message from one of the inputs. It will then run continuously at the
# frequency specified here, regardless of whether it receives more measurements. Defaults to 30 if unspecified.
        frequency: 30.0
        
# ekf_localization_node and ukf_localization_node both use a 3D omnidirectional motion model. If this parameter is
# set to true, no 3D information will be used in your state estimate. Use this if you are operating in a planar
# environment and want to ignore the effect of small variations in the ground plane that might otherwise be detected
# by, for example, an IMU. Defaults to false if unspecified.
        two_d_mode: false

# Whether to publish the acceleration state. Defaults to false if unspecified.
        publish_acceleration: true

# Whether to broadcast the transformation over the /tf topic. Defaults to true if unspecified.
        publish_tf: true
        
# 1. Set the map_frame, odom_frame, and base_link frames to the appropriate frame names for your system.
#     1a. If your system does not have a map_frame, just remove it, and make sure "world_frame" is set to the value of odom_frame.
# 2. If you are fusing continuous position data such as wheel encoder odometry, visual odometry, or IMU data, set "world_frame" 
#    to your odom_frame value. This is the default behavior for robot_localization's state estimation nodes.
# 3. If you are fusing global absolute position data that is subject to discrete jumps (e.g., GPS or position updates from landmark 
#    observations) then:
#     3a. Set your "world_frame" to your map_frame value
#     3b. MAKE SURE something else is generating the odom->base_link transform. Note that this can even be another state estimation node 
#         from robot_localization! However, that instance should *not* fuse the global data.
        map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
        odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
        base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
        world_frame: odmom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified
        
        odom0: /odom
        odom0_config: [true,  true,  true,
                       false, false, false,
                       true, true, true,
                       true, true, true,
                       false, false, false]

        imu0: /camera/camera/accel/sample
        imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                      false,  false,  false,
                      false, false, false,
                      false, false, false,
                      true, true, true]
```

the robot urdf file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="sam_bot" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <!-- Define robot constants -->
  <xacro:property name="base_width" value="0.31"/>
  <xacro:property name="base_length" value="0.42"/>
  <xacro:property name="base_height" value="0.18"/>

  <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.10"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_width" value="0.04"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_ygap" value="0.025"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_zoff" value="0.05"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_xoff" value="0.12"/>

  <xacro:property name="caster_xoff" value="0.14"/>

  <!-- Define some commonly used intertial properties  -->
  <xacro:macro name="box_inertia" params="m w h d">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 ${pi/2}"/>      
      <mass value="${m}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${(m/12) * (h*h + d*d)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="${(m/12) * (w*w + d*d)}" iyz="0.0" izz="${(m/12) * (w*w + h*h)}"/>
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="cylinder_inertia" params="m r h">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0" />      
      <mass value="${m}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${(m/12) * (3*r*r + h*h)}" ixy = "0" ixz = "0" iyy="${(m/12) * (3*r*r + h*h)}" iyz = "0" izz="${(m/2) * (r*r)}"/> 
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="sphere_inertia" params="m r">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="${m}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${(2/5) * m * (r*r)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="${(2/5) * m * (r*r)}" iyz="0.0" izz="${(2/5) * m * (r*r)}"/>
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>
  
  <!-- Robot Base -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${base_length} ${base_width} ${base_height}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Cyan">
        <color rgba="0 1.0 1.0 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${base_length} ${base_width} ${base_height}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="15" w="${base_width}" d="${base_length}" h="${base_height}"/>
  </link>
  
   <!-- Robot Footprint -->
  <link name="base_footprint">
    <xacro:box_inertia m="0" w="0" d="0" h="0"/>
  </link>

  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="base_footprint"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 ${-(wheel_radius+wheel_zoff)}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <!-- Wheels -->
  <xacro:macro name="wheel" params="prefix x_reflect y_reflect">
    <link name="${prefix}_link">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Gray">
          <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0"/>
        </material>
      </visual>

      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/> 
        <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="0.5" r="${wheel_radius}" h="${wheel_width}"/>
    </link>

    <joint name="${prefix}_joint" type="continuous">
      <parent link="base_link"/>
      <child link="${prefix}_link"/>
      <origin xyz="${x_reflect*wheel_xoff} ${y_reflect*(base_width/2+wheel_ygap)} ${-wheel_zoff}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    </joint>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:wheel prefix="drivewhl_l" x_reflect="-1" y_reflect="1" />
  <xacro:wheel prefix="drivewhl_r" x_reflect="-1" y_reflect="-1" />

  <link name="front_caster">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="${(wheel_radius+wheel_zoff-(base_height/2))}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Cyan">
        <color rgba="0 1.0 1.0 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="${(wheel_radius+wheel_zoff-(base_height/2))}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:sphere_inertia m="0.5" r="${(wheel_radius+wheel_zoff-(base_height/2))}"/>
  </link>

  <joint name="caster_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="front_caster"/>
    <origin xyz="${caster_xoff} 0.0 ${-(base_height/2)}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="imu_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
      
    <xacro:box_inertia m="0.1" w="0.1" d="0.1" h="0.1"/>
  </link>
    
  <joint name="imu_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="imu_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.01"/>
  </joint>
    
  <gazebo reference="imu_link">
    <sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so" name="imu_plugin">
        <ros>
          <namespace>/demo</namespace>
          <remapping>~/out:=imu</remapping>
        </ros>
        <initial_orientation_as_reference>false</initial_orientation_as_reference>
      </plugin>
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <update_rate>100</update_rate>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
     <imu>
        <angular_velocity>
          <x>
            <noise type="gaussian">
              <mean>0.0</mean>
              <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
              <bias_mean>0.0000075</bias_mean>
              <bias_stddev>0.0000008</bias_stddev>
            </noise>
          </x>
          <y>
            <noise type="gaussian">
              <mean>0.0</mean>
              <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
              <bias_mean>0.0000075</bias_mean>
              <bias_stddev>0.0000008</bias_stddev>
            </noise>
          </y>
          <z>
            <noise type="gaussian">
              <mean>0.0</mean>
              <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
              <bias_mean>0.0000075</bias_mean>
              <bias_stddev>0.0000008</bias_stddev>
            </noise>
          </z>
        </angular_velocity>
        <linear_acceleration>
          <x>
            <noise type="gaussian">
              <mean>0.0</mean>
              <stddev>1.7e-2</stddev>
              <bias_mean>0.1</bias_mean>
              <bias_stddev>0.001</bias_stddev>
            </noise>
          </x>
          <y>
            <noise type="gaussian">
              <mean>0.0</mean>
              <stddev>1.7e-2</stddev>
              <bias_mean>0.1</bias_mean>
              <bias_stddev>0.001</bias_stddev>
            </noise>
          </y>
          <z>
            <noise type="gaussian">
              <mean>0.0</mean>
              <stddev>1.7e-2</stddev>
              <bias_mean>0.1</bias_mean>
              <bias_stddev>0.001</bias_stddev>
            </noise>
          </z>
        </linear_acceleration>
      </imu>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
 
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name='diff_drive' filename='libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so'>
      <ros>
        <namespace>/demo</namespace>
      </ros>

      <!-- wheels -->
      <left_joint>drivewhl_l_joint</left_joint>
      <right_joint>drivewhl_r_joint</right_joint>

      <!-- kinematics -->
      <wheel_separation>0.4</wheel_separation>
      <wheel_diameter>0.2</wheel_diameter>

      <!-- limits -->   
      <max_wheel_torque>20</max_wheel_torque>
      <max_wheel_acceleration>1.0</max_wheel_acceleration>

      <!-- output -->
      <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
      <publish_odom_tf>false</publish_odom_tf>
      <publish_wheel_tf>true</publish_wheel_tf>

      <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
      <robot_base_frame>base_link</robot_base_frame>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

 <link name="lidar_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="0.125"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.001"  ixy="0"  ixz="0" iyy="0.001" iyz="0" izz="0.001" />
    </inertial>

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
         <cylinder radius="0.0508" length="0.055"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
         <cylinder radius="0.0508" length="0.055"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
    
  <joint name="lidar_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="lidar_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.12" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
    
  <gazebo reference="lidar_link">
    <sensor name="lidar" type="ray">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>5</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>360</samples>
            <resolution>1.000000</resolution>
            <min_angle>0.000000</min_angle>
            <max_angle>6.280000</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.120000</min>
          <max>3.5</max>
          <resolution>0.015000</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.01</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="scan" filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so">
        <ros>
          <remapping>~/out:=scan</remapping>
        </ros>
        <output_type>sensor_msgs/LaserScan</output_type>
        <frame_name>laser_link</frame_name>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  
  <link name="camera_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.015 0.130 0.022"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.015 0.130 0.022"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="0.035"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.001"  ixy="0"  ixz="0" iyy="0.001" iyz="0" izz="0.001" />
    </inertial>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="camera_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.215 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="camera_depth_frame"/>

  <joint name="camera_depth_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${-pi/2} 0 ${-pi/2}"/>
    <parent link="camera_link"/>
    <child link="camera_depth_frame"/>
  </joint>

  <gazebo reference="camera_link">
    <sensor name="depth_camera" type="depth">
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
      <camera name="camera">
        <horizontal_fov>1.047198</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>480</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.05</near>
          <far>3</far>
        </clip>
      </camera>
      <plugin name="depth_camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <baseline>0.2</baseline>
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
        <frame_name>camera_depth_frame</frame_name>
        <pointCloudCutoff>0.5</pointCloudCutoff>
        <pointCloudCutoffMax>3.0</pointCloudCutoffMax>
        <distortionK1>0</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0</distortionT2>
        <CxPrime>0</CxPrime>
        <Cx>0</Cx>
        <Cy>0</Cy>
        <focalLength>0</focalLength>
        <hackBaseline>0</hackBaseline>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

and the launch file is

```
import launch
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
import launch_ros
import os

def generate_launch_description():
    pkg_share = launch_ros.substitutions.FindPackageShare(package='amr_bot').find('amr_bot')
    default_model_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'src/description/amr_bot_description.urdf')
    default_rviz_config_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'rviz/urdf_config.rviz')
    world_path=os.path.join(pkg_share, 'world/my_world.sdf')
    
    robot_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': Command(['xacro ', LaunchConfiguration('model')])}]
    )
    joint_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        name='joint_state_publisher',
        condition=launch.conditions.UnlessCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
    )
    rviz_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['-d', LaunchConfiguration('rvizconfig')],
    )
    spawn_entity = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='gazebo_ros', 
        executable='spawn_entity.py',
        arguments=['-entity', 'amr_bot', '-topic', 'robot_description'],
        output='screen'
    )
    robot_localization_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
         package='robot_localization',
         executable='ekf_node',
         name='ekf_filter_node',
         output='screen',
         parameters=[os.path.join(pkg_share, 'config/ekf.yaml'), {'use_sim_time': LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')}]
    )

    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='gui', default_value='True',
                                            description='Flag to enable joint_state_publisher_gui'),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='model', default_value=default_model_path,
                                            description='Absolute path to robot urdf file'),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='rvizconfig', default_value=default_rviz_config_path,
                                            description='Absolute path to rviz config file'),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='use_sim_time', default_value='True',
                                            description='Flag to enable use_sim_time'),
        launch.actions.ExecuteProcess(cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_init.so', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so', world_path], output='screen'),
        joint_state_publisher_node,
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        spawn_entity,
        robot_localization_node,
        rviz_node
    ])
```

and the slam_toolbox params_file is

```
slam_toolbox:
  ros__parameters:

    # Plugin params
    solver_plugin: solver_plugins::CeresSolver
    ceres_linear_solver: SPARSE_NORMAL_CHOLESKY
    ceres_preconditioner: SCHUR_JACOBI
    ceres_trust_strategy: LEVENBERG_MARQUARDT
    ceres_dogleg_type: TRADITIONAL_DOGLEG
    ceres_loss_function: None

    # ROS Parameters
    odom_frame: odom
    map_frame: map
    base_frame: base_footprint
    scan_topic: /scan
    mode: localization

    # if you'd like to immediately start continuing a map at a given pose
    # or at the dock, but they are mutually exclusive, if pose is given
    # will use pose
    map_file_name: /home/omni/map
    # map_start_pose: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    map_start_at_dock: true

    debug_logging: false
    throttle_scans: 1
    transform_publish_period: 0.02 #if 0 never publishes odometry
    map_update_interval: 5.0
    resolution: 0.05
    max_laser_range: 20.0 #for rastering images
    minimum_time_interval: 0.5
    transform_timeout: 0.2
    tf_buffer_duration: 30.
    stack_size_to_use: 40000000 #// program needs a larger stack size to serialize large maps
    enable_interactive_mode: true

    # General Parameters
    use_scan_matching: true
    use_scan_barycenter: true
    minimum_travel_distance: 0.5
    minimum_travel_heading: 0.5
    scan_buffer_size: 50
    scan_buffer_maximum_scan_distance: 10.0
    link_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.1  
    link_scan_maximum_distance: 1.5
    loop_search_maximum_distance: 3.0
    do_loop_closing: true 
    loop_match_minimum_chain_size: 10           
    loop_match_maximum_variance_coarse: 3.0  
    loop_match_minimum_response_coarse: 0.35    
    loop_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.45

    # Correlation Parameters - Correlation Parameters
    correlation_search_space_dimension: 0.5
    correlation_search_space_resolution: 0.01
    correlation_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.1 

    # Correlation Parameters - Loop Closure Parameters
    loop_search_space_dimension: 8.0
    loop_search_space_resolution: 0.05
    loop_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.03

    # Scan Matcher Parameters
    distance_variance_penalty: 0.5      
    angle_variance_penalty: 1.0    

    fine_search_angle_offset: 0.00349     
    coarse_search_angle_offset: 0.349   
    coarse_angle_resolution: 0.0349        
    minimum_angle_penalty: 0.9
    minimum_distance_penalty: 0.5
    use_response_expansion: true
```

Im running the launch file then

```
ros2 run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0.1 0 0.2 0 0 0 base_link laser_link
```

then the slam_toolbox with `ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py slam_params_file:=./src/amr_one/config/mapper_params_online_async.yaml use_sim_time:=false` and navigation with `ros2 launch nav2_bringup navigation_launch.py`

So everything ok but in rviz got the error as can see from the screenshot[image: RVIZ2].. Any Help?